# Remove text from Javascript string

Tags: javascript, html, string

given below is the picture of the response I get on submitting a form with wrong email.
[image: my response image]

I want to remove the word ***message:*** & curly brackets around the string from this response. I am trying the following:

```
$('#registerStatus').text(response.replace('message:', ''))
```

But it doesnt work. Can you please help?

Comment: Is response an object?

Comment: Wherever you are displaying `response` change it to `response.message`.

Comment: Add the logs for `console.log(response)` and `typeof response`. Post the values here.

Comment: @adiga log for (response) gives {"message":"Email already exists"}
& log for typeof response gives string

Comment: You have a JSON string. You need parse it to an object before adding it to text: `var o = JSON.parse(response); $('#registerStatus').text(o.message)`

Comment: You can close it as a duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383)

Answer (score 3):

The response is a JSON Object, so you can write:

```
$('#registerStatus').text(response.message)
```

Comment: If response was JSON string, it would have quotes around the `message` key.